# How to check for just spaces for validation attribute

Tags: validation, asp.net-core, attributes

I have this is my VM:

```
   [Display(Name = "Reason for Cancellation")]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(245)] // 245 characters to allow for History Type prefix to be added
    public string CancelJustificationComments { get; set; }
```

I have noticed that if the value is a list of spaces then the above validation is ignored - which obviously is how it is coded.

How do I add further validation to trim all the spaces t make sure there is a 'legitimate' value please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do this would be to use a `RegularExpressionAttribute`

```
[Display(Name = "Reason for Cancellation")]
[Required]
[RegularExpression(@"\w")]
[StringLength(245)] // 245 characters to allow for History Type prefix to be added
public string CancelJustificationComments { get; set; }
```

This attribute is often used to force the input format, having the Regex starting with `^` and ending with `$`, in order to check the full string.

With the `\w` regex, you don't check how the string starts or ends, you only say that you need at least one "word character" (`[a-zA-Z0-9]`)

Comment: thanks. I was just getting there myself :)   But I prefer your choice of regular expression I was using   [RegularExpression(@"^[\S]*$")]

Comment: I was hoping you would explain that. Makes sense. Thanks again

Comment: I just added some precision about the ^ and $ in the regex, before seeing your comment ;)

Answer (score 0):

The `[Required]` data annotation has the optional parameter `AllowEmptyStrings` - setting this to `false` will cause model validation to fail on a white-space string.

```
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
```